# Proper way to check the value of completed Promise?

Tags: scala, concurrency, promise

Context: I have a function where I'd like to check in the beginning that a certain Promise has a) already been completed and b) has a certain value.

There is a method to check whether the Promise in Scala (as of 2.11.5) has already been completed, namely `isCompleted`. However, when you want to get a value of the already completed Promise, it looks like you have to write an unappetising chain like this:

```
val p = Promise[Boolean]
val result = p.future.value.get.toOption.get
```

(for completeness: I was thinking about writing something like:

```
if (p.isCompleted && p.future.value.get.toOption.get == true)
```

but was appalled at the ugliness of that code :) )

Is there no better way? Or is it a sign that I am not using it the way it was intended to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future[T].value` returns an `Option[Try[T]]` which is none if the future has not completed so you don't need to also check `isCompleted`. This means you could write the method as:

```
def hasValue[T](p: Promise[T], value: T) = p.future.value.flatMap(_.toOption) == Some(value)
```

Answer (score 5):

I would say you're not using it the way it's intended to be used.

First of all, Scala Promises are primarily a mechanism for "bootstrapping" Futures, so the values you pass around should generally be Futures and not Promises. That makes the chain of accesses one segment shorter.

Next, the reason you are going through so many layers is that Futures encapsulate two effects - concurrency and failure. A Future can be completed and failed, so checking `isCompleted` is only half of the story.

So what you can do here is use pattern matching. The Some/None pattern match checks for completed/not completed, so you don't need to do an explicit check of the `.isCompleted` property.  Here I'll assume you have a Future `f` rather than a Promise, but you could do the same with `p.future` if you needed to):

```
f.value match {
    case Some(Success(v)) => // completed successfully - access value v
    case Some(Failure(e)) => // completed with failure - access error e
    case None => // not yet complete
}
```

In your specific case, this would boil down to what Sarvesh demonstrated in his answer, although I'd say there's a good chance you should actually be handling the *error* and *not complete* cases rather than just treating them as `false`.

The other way to use Futures is to use them in an event-driven way. You can register events on `f.andThen`, `f.onFailure`, `f.onSuccess` depending on which outcomes you want to observe, and you can use use a variety of other mechanisms for transforming their results and so on.

Answer (score 0):

So... basically a promise is a wrapper kind of thing, which allows us to interact with underlying future.

So... just get your future from the completed promise and use pattern matching.

In this case, p.future.value will be a `Option[ Try [ Boolean ] ]`

```
val yourBool = p.future.value match {
  case Some( Success( bool ) ) => bool
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: To whomsoever it may concern - Please comment if you want to downvote. It helps me learn about the mistake in my answer.